# Use custom style and ListSelector for ListView items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-styles

In my app I have a ListView with items which have this style:

```
<style name="GoogleNowCardStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/search_bg_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/GoogleNowCardMinHeight</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#707070</item>
</style>
```

Now my problem is that I have to select these items in the ListView so I have to add:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

to my main ListView item layout. But this line overwrites the background atribute from the style. How can I use both of these at the same time on my ListView items?

Comment: Is ?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator background of the list view or the list view's item?

Comment: Both are on the item. The `activatedBackgroundIndicator` and the `GoogleNowCardStyle`

Comment: Well... obviously you can't set the background twice and expect it to combine. That's why you have to use a custom stateList/selector drawable that provides the combined(by you) backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create a [`StateList`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) drawable resource that has a `state_selected` item and use it as a background for your listItem. When the listItem's state changes to `selected` it will load the drawable that was set for the `state_selected` item in your state list.

Comment: But I really want to use the default ListSelector